# Unable to Spawn a New Thread in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I am launching my JAR with Applescripts that reside inside my objective-c code.

I want to perform this operation in a new thread (NSThread).

note: I have used GCD but it doesn't help me as even the concurrent queue has a 
dependency on the main thread.

```
-(void) launchJar{
        NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptToLaunch];
    [script executeAndReturnError:nil];

    NSLog(@"hitting this point");
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            MCMCustomURLSchemeHandler *mcmCustomURLHandler = [[MCMCustomURLSchemeHandler alloc] init];


                  [NSThread detachNewThreadWithBlock:@selector(launchJar) toTarget:[JARLauncher class] withObject:nil];



            return NSApplicationMain(argc, argv);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the statements of `launchJar` into an autorelease pool:

```
- (void)launchJar {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptToLaunch];
        [script executeAndReturnError:nil];
        NSLog(@"hitting this point");
    }
}
```

BTW: You should avoid launching threads with `NSThread` directly. Try `NSOperationQueue` or GCD instead.

Comment: I followed your advice and got it running. I also had an issue with where i was placing my launchJar method. 

Solving this made me realize of another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904677/how-do-i-ensure-that-i-close-my-app-only-when-all-the-threads-have-finished-exec

Could you take a look at it ?