# How do i ensure that i close my app only when all the threads have finished execution in objective - c

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I have the following code

```
@interface MCMCustomURLSchemeHandler : NSObject
- (void)getUrl:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event
withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent;
@end

@implementation MCMCustomURLSchemeHandler

- (void)getUrl:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)event
withReplyEvent:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)replyEvent
{
    // Get the URL
    NSString *urlStr = [[event paramDescriptorForKeyword:keyDirectObject]
                        stringValue];
    NSLog(@" CUSTOM URL %@", urlStr);

    //TODO: Your custom URL handling code here
}

@end

@interface MyObject : NSObject
+(void)aMethod:(id)param;
@end

@implementation MyObject
+(void)aMethod:(id)param{

    @autoreleasepool {
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:scriptToLaunch];
    [script executeAndReturnError:nil];

    NSLog(@"hitting this point");
    }
}
@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

    MCMCustomURLSchemeHandler *mcmCustomURLHandler = [[MCMCustomURLSchemeHandler alloc] init];

    NSAppleEventManager *em = [NSAppleEventManager sharedAppleEventManager];
    [em
     setEventHandler:mcmCustomURLHandler
     andSelector:@selector(getUrl:withReplyEvent:)
     forEventClass:kInternetEventClass
     andEventID:kAEGetURL];

        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(aMethod:) toTarget:[MyObject class] withObject:nil];

        //sleep(10000);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

---

In the MyObject method, i am launching a Jar. Till i quit my Jar, i do not get a callback.

How do i ensure that my app continues to be in running state when my thread is listening to the Jar.

I need the app to be in a functional position (sleep won't help) because it has to listen to some other events (custom URL).

Comment: Why does your app want to run the script in parallel? What does the main thread when the script is running?

Comment: @macmoonshine running the JAR is a blocking call. Till i quit the jar i do not get the access back to my application. I need my objective-c to be free to handle any custom url calls made. (I have registered my app against a custom URL).

Comment: You need a run loop.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad could you please elaborate ?

Comment: If you have a specific questions about run loops after reading the documentation, create a new Q, please.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Hi Amin, i think run loops might do the trick, but the documentation for it seems scarce. Could you please help me providing a sample application or documentation / video for it.